# Daily Refreshed Table, will I benefit from SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, in-memory-database

I have number of massive tables which refreshes on daily basis, and I then run queries to power all the reports for my company. I'm wondering if upgrading to SQL Server 2014 and utilizing in-memory OLTP would benefit.

Some told me that in-memory is beneficial for database that does high volume of updates in realtime. is this true? None of my tables update in real-time, they're all pulled from another datasource on nightly basis.

Comment: Sounds like columnstore would be more relevant.

Comment: The in-memory OLTP helps to reduce locking & latching, which probably isn't your issue -- and since it's memory only tables, it's really not for massive tables, since you're going to run out of memory. Like @MartinSmith mentioned, column store indexes might help.

Comment: What do you mean by massive tables?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits, by massive tables, I meant many of them more than 20 columns with >1M rows, with no real way of indexing unfortunately...